# How to export the whole application in one workspace and import it to other in APEX?

Tags: oracle, import, export, oracle-apex, workspace

I need one app and I need exactly the same in another workspace. So is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Export it, log into the other workspace, and Import it.

If the workspaces are on the same database instance, you will need to assign a new application ID to the application. If you use the GUI to do this it will offer this option to you automatically.

Comment: I assume that by GUI you mean using Apex backend application. Are there any other ways of importing/exporting apps ?

Comment: Hi @Jestem_z_Kozanowa, yes you can export and import applications from SQL*Plus. You can export using `WWV_FLOW_UTILITIES.export_application_to_clob` as per http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2013/05/22/deploying-application-express-on-the-command-line/ which you can then write to a SQL script. You can then use the same script to import the application.